# Link $http cache to jwt sub in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, caching, jwt

Are there any libraries or techniques for bolting on a user-specific cache for my data services?  Blinding caching `$http` calls won't work since the data for each user is different.  For example, performing a `GET` on `/api/addresses` will return the addresses in **that** user's contact list.  Whenever a user is logged in, their `$auth` token has a `sub` (`user_id`) element so I'd like the cache to be tied to the currently logged in user.

Comment: `...so I'd like the cache to be tied to the currently logged in user` can't you just include the user's id in the cache key?

Comment: All of the examples I've found set the `$http.defaults.cache` in the `app.run`.  Unfortunately, the user is not logged in at that point.  Doing it in the login controller seems very messy.

Comment: Have you tried alternatives like [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache)?

Comment: Just started reading through the docs for angular-cache.  I came to SO, however, because I have to believe someone has already built a more intelligent http cache (taking into account security, object updates, etc.).  It's a bit surprising that, regardless of what underlying cache service I use, that I'm rolling my own.